# onClick use jsZip to zip up multiple images src on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have 2 images being displayed on a page. Both images are `data:base64`. I have made them downloadable via HTML5 `download` attribute.  It is a great interaction but there will be potentially many images for download on a page. How do I use `jsZip` to  download any images with class of `zip-me`: I would like the trigger to be `onClick` of `id="zip-btn"`.

Please view the live demo:

### **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53umT/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img src="base64string" class="zip-me" />
  <a href="base64string" download="image1.png" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="base64string"  class="zip-me" />
  <a href="base64string" download="image2.png" />
</div>
<button id="zip-btn" onClick="downloadZip()"> Download Zip </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you call .file() it adds another file to the zip. You just need to grab the base64 from your image src's and specify a base64 file type in the options parameter. This is from jszip's documentation:

```
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
zip.file("smile.gif", "R0lGODdhBQAFAIACAAAAAP/eACwAAAAABQAFAAACCIwPkWerClIBADs=", {base64:     true});
zip.file("magic.txt", "U2VjcmV0IGNvZGU=", {base64: true, binary: false});
zip.file("Xmas.txt", "Ho ho ho !", {date : new Date("December 25, 2007 00:00:01")});
zip.file("folder/file.txt", "file in folder");

zip.file("animals.txt", "dog,platypus\n").file("people.txt", "james,sebastian\n");

// result : Hello.txt, smile.gif, magic.txt, Xmas.txt, animals.txt, people.txt,
// folder/, folder/file.txt
```

Comment: also needs a create and return object  But it works... i've edited your code